# Why my button in Leaflet popup not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, popup

I have a leaflet map with a lot of markers, when they are click some information appears with an edit and delete button! For some reason however leaflet seems to mask these buttons, either way they simply won't work.

here is my map component with the markers and popups:

```
refresh() {
    this.artworkService.retrieveAll().then((artworkList) => {
      this.artworkList = artworkList;
      for (let artwork of this.artworkList) {
        const popupOptions = { className: "customPopup" };
       const popupContent =
          "<span class='customPopup'><b>" +
          artwork.name +
          "</b></span>" +
          "<br/>" +
          artwork.filename +
           "<br/>" +
          artwork.firstname + " " + artwork.lastname +
          "<br/>" +
          artwork.streetname + artwork.streetnumber + ", " + artwork.zipcode +
          "<br/>" +
          "<button (click)='editArtwork()'><i class='fa fa-edit mr-1></i></button>" + "<i class='fa fa-trash ml-1 (click)='deleteArtwork()'></i>";
    console.log(artwork.name);
        L.marker([artwork.latitude, artwork.longitude], this.markerIcon)
          .addTo(this.map)
          .bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions);
      }
   });
}

editArtwork() {
  alert("editing");
}

deleteArtwork() {
  alert("deleteing");
}
```

i click on the button and nothing happens, nothing shows up in the console either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your button is not working because your are trying to invoke a method which resides in a string practically

```
 "<button (click)='editArtwork()'><i class='fa fa-edit mr-1></i></button>" + "<i class='fa fa-trash ml-1 (click)='deleteArtwork()'></i>";
```

is a string assigned to a variable not html that is the reason your method invocation does not work.

Not sure if this is the best approach but one approach would be to:
1. assign a unique class to each button
2. use on("popupopen") event handler in combination with angular's `elementRef` like in the following example:

```
const popupOptions = {
  className: "customPopup"
};
const _this = this;

for (let artwork of this.artworkList) {
  const popupInfo = `
  ${artwork.name} <br> ${
    artwork.filename
  } <br> <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  <br> <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  `;
  L.marker([artwork.latitude, artwork.longitude], this.markerIcon)
    .addTo(this.map)
    .bindPopup(popupInfo, popupOptions)
    .on("popupopen", () => {
      _this.elementRef.nativeElement
        .querySelector(".edit")
        .addEventListener("click", e => {
          _this.editArtwork();
        });
    })
    .on("popupopen", () => {
      _this.elementRef.nativeElement
        .querySelector(".delete")
        .addEventListener("click", e => {
          _this.deleteArtwork();
        });
    });
}



editArtwork() {
  alert("editing");
}

deleteArtwork() {
  alert("deleting");
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/l3l468y5w7)

Comment: Could you briefly explain the significance of "const _this = this;"? Would much appreciate it!

Comment: Actually you can ignore it and use `this` instead of `_this` since es6 is used. If you would not use es6 you would need it because `const _this = this;` keeps a reference of the `class AppComponent` to be able to access its private variable `elementRef` or any other public or private component variable inside a nested scope (function inside a for loop inside a function). As the scope of `this` changes inside addEventListener function, loses its reference to the class and becomes undefined. But since es6 is used it does exactly the same job as if you would use `const _this = this`.

Answer (score 2):

Someone might find this useful, I was facing the same issue, I fixed it with getPopup method as my ElemenRef.NativeElement was unable to find the element to assign the event,

```
for (let artwork of this.artworkList) {
  const popupInfo = `
  ${artwork.name} <br> ${
    artwork.filename
  } <br> <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  <br> <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  `;
  L.marker([artwork.latitude, artwork.longitude], this.markerIcon)
    .addTo(this.map)
    .bindPopup(popupInfo, popupOptions)
    .on("popupopen", (a) => {
         var popUp = a.target.getPopup()
         popUp.getElement()
        .querySelector(".edit")
        .addEventListener("click", e => {
          _this.editArtwork();
        });
    })    
}



editArtwork() {
  alert("editing");
}
```