# Is it a bad practice to add HostListener to target the clicks on the document, and then check if the class matches?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Is this code considered as a bad practice:

```
   @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
      clickout(event: any) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains("my-class"))
    {
    //do somthing
    }
```

Comment: you can find direct the element after render your HTML and add the event like so:
`document.getElementsByClassName('your-class').addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this))`

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes - kind of. I mean if you could attach `(click)` listener directly on the target then you would only have to listen clicks on those targets, no need for additional queries either. Right now your listening to **every** click and then on top of that, querying classes on whatever target that click happens to land on - highly resource intensive way compared to attaching the listener on the right target in the first place.

```html
<div class="my-class" (click)="onClick()"></div>
```

```js
onClick() {
// do something
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because I'm adding the html as string and it seems that it is not using angular to do so.

can you please check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54363523/10922278

Comment: So I understand there you ended up using `.addEventListener("click")`? Click listener could invoke more than one method if needs be.

Comment: well now I've two options:
1-add `.addEventListener("click")` after getting the elements by class or id.
2-use HostListener on the document, which is much easier to apply.
so I'm wondering how bad is it to do so.

Comment: Resource wise, probably not **that** bad - "best practise" wise like you asked? Pretty bad. My advice is: don't cut corners if you know there is a better solution out there - even if it's the longer way to do things. But at the end of the day, your the one writing this code - do whatever works best for you.